# How to check if variable is whole in C++ without a math library

Tags: c++, math

I'm writing a little program for a beginner C++ class, I'm supposed to take an input (I'm using double, because I like to make things harder for myself) from a user and output whether it's prime or composite, and if it's composite, I need to output at least one number which the number is divisible by.

I have too much time on my hands so I'm going a little out of my way to make it harder. I'm trying to do everything without using anything but iostream. I've gotten most of it, but this bit is stumping me: How can I determine if a double is an integer without using a math library?(I found questions that had good solutions using math.h here, but nothing without it) I'd like to think there's a way to do it without writing fifty lines of code for something that seems so simple ...

Comment: Is the input floating point or an integer? If it is an integer, you can probably work this out without using `double`s in your program.

Comment: "I have too much time on my hands" - have you tried a harder class? :P

Comment: David: I'm using a double. It wouldn't be a problem if the input was an integer ;)

Comment: @Mystical Hehe. There's that, but I like to challenge myself at my own pace. I'm in the reserves, among other things, so I don't *always* have spare time.

Comment: @DanielBall: The question is not so much what you are using, but rather what the specification of the problem says :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not be doing any computations in floating point, but a simple way of testing whether a number has decimals or not is taking the floor and comparing it with the original. In C++ you can take the floor by converting to an `int` (assuming only positive numbers) and then converting back to `double`:

```
bool isWhole( double d ) {
   int whole = d;               // will round down to the nearest integer
   return (d-whole < epsilon);  // for a small enough epsilon
}
```

Comment: @DanielBall: The specification is a common problem on integers, if the inputs are integer numbers, then you can either operate on `double`s and have to manage the floating point, or else operate only on integers and then rounding would not be an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ... if I want a user to be able to input a fractional number, don't I *have* to use a floating point type?

Comment: @DanielBall: What would be the definition of *prime* for a fractional number? Is 1.5 prime? Is it composite? What would be the factors?

Comment: A prime number is a natural number divisible only by one and itself. I'm aware that they shouldn't be putting in non-natural numbers ... If you're referring to the actual prime check not using doubles, couldn't I just convert it to an int after I've determined that the input is whole?

Comment: @DanielBall: Think whether it makes sense to allow the user to input values for which they know the answer upfront. What value does accepting floating point values add to your program? If I was writing the program, I would not take non-integers as input.

Comment: As this is an educational effort for myself, the value of the program is determined by what I can learn from it. Were I writing this for a user that wasn't me, you are absolutely right, I would not take them as input.

Comment: That isn't `floor` for negatives.

Comment: It should be called `IsAlmostWhole` for `epsilon>0`. If you want to know whether `d` is an integer, just use `d-int(d)==0`. Be aware though that `(1.0/3.0)*3.0` probably is not an integer.

Comment: @oldrinb: That is the reason for the comment *(assuming only positive numbers)* in the answer.

Comment: @MSalters: That is exactly the reason for the *epsilon* test, comparing floating point numbers for equality is tricky. That is also a good reason to avoid `double` in the problem.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: But the question wasn't about equality of calculated results. The question was whether a given input, parsed as a `double`, had a fractional part. With doubles, the trick is to know when to use inexact comparisons. "Always" is just as wrong as "never".

Comment: Negative numbers get filtered out by an if/else before it gets to the whole number check in what I wrote, so negatives wouldn't be an issue.

What is an epsilon?

Comment: @DanielBall: A small enough value that you don't really care about, so that two values that differ in less that that difference are considered equal. If epsilon is 10^-10, then you are saying that in your domain `1+10^-11` while it is not technically `1` should be considered as one. Consider that as a rounding factor

Comment: Ok ... I see the point of the epsilon given what @MSalters said, but why would (1.0/3.0)*3.0 not be an integer?

Comment: @DanielBall: If you compare with == there can be rounding issues. The number after the division (in decimal) would be 0.33333333__, and that times 3 is 0.999999999__ which is not exactly 1. That is the value of using an epsilon to compare, you don't really care whether it is exactly 1, if there is a difference of 10^-10 it is kind of 1

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `double` value to a suitably large integer type, then see if the two values are the same:

```
double d = /* whatever */
long long ival = d;
if (ival == d) {
    /* d holds integral value. */
}
```